# Make some community ads!

Tags: discussion

I discovered this site by happy accident while browsing Twitter and saw a question shared by the StackExchange account.

Perhaps you should reach out a bit more and get some people from other communities? The easiest way is to post community ads, for example on this thread on [Physics](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388/community-promotion-ads-2015) (There are similar threads on [Math](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19014/community-promotion-ads-2015) and [Theoretical CS](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2875/community-promotion-ads-2015)).

It should get you a nice boost in participants, plus more crossover between related communities.

Comment: Awesome idea; we need this. I haven't done one of these before; how can I make an ad?

Comment: @HDE226868 just make an image of the size mentioned in the question.

Comment: I'm not too tech-savvy; I honestly have no idea how to do that. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @HDE226868 use Paint/Photoshop/GIMP/some other image editor?

Comment: Okay, thanks, I'll get started.

Comment: We need to advertise something that is relevant to the history of Science and Mathematics. What would this be?

Comment: @HDE226868 I am under the impression for "betas" there is a standard thing. See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/12775/ for a live example. And I have seen exactly that layout with changed name plenty of times. I do not know where to find this/how to get it though. Perhaps someones knows or we jsut ask a CM.

Comment: Can someone with a Theoretical CS account put it on Theoretical CS?

Answer (score 7):

After some digging around on area51 I found the image I knew must exist.

[image: Stack Exchange Q&A beta site: History of Science and Mathematics]

Putting the text below into an answer in the respective threads is all that would be needed I think (in addition to getting some votes there, then).

`<a href="http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/65204/"><img src="http://area51.stackexchange.com/ads/proposal/65204.png" width="220" height="250" alt="Stack Exchange Q&A  beta site: History of Science and Mathematics" /></a>`

Comment: Something more innovative/eye-catching would be nice. These ads get shown anyway iirc.

Comment: AFAIK only proposals in commitment get shown.

Comment: I've posted this image on both the Physics and Mathematics Community Ads threads; I hope it gets upvoted enough (Net score of 6). If we come up with a better one, I'll change the picture.

Comment: Is there anything more discreet then this and that will disappear automatically after a while?  If yes, I'm willing to add it to all my new answers on AskUbuntu (And I have a shipload of answers...).  Tons of scientists use Ubuntu and something like that would attract attention to a bunch of new users...

Comment: @Fabby it is kind you want to help promote the site, but I believe this form of promotion would not be appreciated, even if it were relatively discreet.

Comment: Yup...  Just came back in to delete my comment as I got some feed-back from thet chat room that it would be a bad idea...  (but now leaving it where it is as you've already said the same thing!)  **;-)**

Answer (score 6):

**Suggested Targets**

- [Physics](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388/community-promotion-ads-2015) - Net score of [13](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388/community-promotion-ads-2015/6406#6406)
- [Mathematics](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19014/community-promotion-ads-2015) - Net score of [23](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19014/community-promotion-ads-2015/19087#19087)
- [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2875/community-promotion-ads-2015) - Not yet posted, as I have no account. Anyone up for it?
- [Skeptics](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3023/community-promotion-ads-2015) - Net score of [2](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3023/community-promotion-ads-2015/3034#3034)
- [Chemistry](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2696/community-promotion-ads-2015) - Net score of [2](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2696/community-promotion-ads-2015/2698#2698)

Answer (score 4):

I've made a rudimentary ad in Paint:

[image]

The figure is Archimedes, based on [pizza's comment here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19014/community-promotion-ads-2015/19087#comment69647_19087). I modified [this file](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e7/Domenico-Fetti_Archimedes_1620.jpg/180px-Domenico-Fetti_Archimedes_1620.jpg). I was going to use [this](http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3395/3635236894_06500c03e2_z.jpg), but it's copyrighted.

I'll use this ad to replace the temporary one we have at the moment.

Comment: on the subject of Archimedes someone should draw like blood splattered circles with the text HSM on it.