# Let's make our own site promotion ad!

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

This is a spin-off of ManishEarth's earlier meta post,
[Make some community ads!](https://hsm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119/make-some-community-ads)

> #### What are Community Promotion Ads?
>
> Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will
>   show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this
>   question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are
>   provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be
>   shown.
>
> #### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?
>
> This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to
>   visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following
>   things:
>
> - the site's twitter account
> - useful tools or resources for physics research
> - interesting articles or findings for the curious
> - cool events or conferences
> - anything else your community would genuinely be interested in
>
> The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your
>   community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote
>   information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's
>   interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to
>   join.
>
> #### Why do we reset the ads every year?
>
> Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other
>   things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads
>   every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served
>   their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This
>   helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject
>   matter of the community, but to the current status of the community.
>   We reset the ads once a year, every December.
>
> The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an
>   ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very
>   valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good
>   idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the
>   process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale
>   after a year of exposure.
>
> #### How does it work?
>
> The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following
>   rules, or they will be ignored.
>
> 1. All answers should be in the exact form of:
>
>    ```
>    [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]
>
>       [1]: http://image-url
>       [2]: http://clickthrough-url
>    ```
>
>    Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
> 2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the
>      functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the
>      answer form with the above required form.
>
> #### Image requirements
>
> - The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
> - Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
> - Must be GIF or PNG
> - No animated GIFs
> - Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

Our ads should be sort of like a visual version of an elevator pitch - visually succinct enough that people don't get bored reading them, but also detailed enough that they show some of the site's personality. The phrase "History of Math and Science" on, say, a green background, won't really cut it.

The ads should reflect the theme of the site in some way - for example, using an image of Rafael's [The School of Athens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_School_of_Athens). Let's make them colorful and creative.

Post a suggestion as an "answer" to this "question." The ads with the most votes will be submitted in place of our unofficially-default ad marking our days in beta. If you have an fledgling idea, feel free to share it in [On the Shoulders of Giants](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18230/on-the-shoulders-of-giants), our chat room. Or just go ahead and post it!

Let's show Stack Exchange what our site is about!

---

For more information, see [What's the best way to create a community ad for a beta site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247037/whats-the-best-way-to-create-a-community-ad-for-a-beta-site) on Meta.

Comment: I'd be curious as to who downvoted. Are you against community promotion?